# Informix: How to get the table contents and column names using dbaccess?

Tags: informix, dbaccess

Supposing I have:

- an Informix database named "my_database"
- a table named "my_table" with the columns "col_1", "col_2" and "col_3":

I can extract the contents of the table by creating a **my_table.sql** script like:

```
unload to "my_table.txt"
select * from my_table;
```

and invoking dbaccess from the command line:

```
dbaccess my_database my_table.sql
```

This will produce the **my_table.txt** file with contents like:

```
value_a1|value_a2|value_a3
value_b1|value_b2|value_b3
```

Now, what do I have to do if I want to obtain the column names in the **my_table.txt**? Like:

```
col_1|col_2|col_3
value_a1|value_a2|value_a3
value_b1|value_b2|value_b3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

None of the standard Informix tools put the column names at the top of the output as you want.

The program SQLCMD (not the Microsoft newcomer - the original one, available from the [IIUG Software Archive](https://www.iiug.org/en/iiug-software-repository/#ESQL)) has the ability to do that; use the `-H` option for the column headings (and `-T` to get the column types).

```
sqlcmd -U -d my_database -t my_table -HT -o my_table.txt
sqlunload -d my_database -t my_table -HT -o my_table.txt
```

SQLCMD also can do CSV output if that's what you need (but — bug — it doesn't format the column names or column types lines correctly).

Answer (score 2):

Why you don't use dbschema?

To get schema of one table (without -t parameter show all database)

```
dbschema -d [DBName] -t [DBTable] > file.sql
```

To get schema of one stored procedure

```
dbschema -d [DBName] -f [SPName] > file.sql
```

Answer (score 0):

Found an easier solution. Place the headers in one file say `header.txt` (it will contain a single line "`col_1|col_2|col_3`") then to combine the header file and your output file run:

```
cat header.txt my_table.txt > my_table_wth_head.txt
```